# RoR: ActiveRecord and disqualifying with associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to figure out how to disqualify records in a query that are found in an associated table.

I have 3 tables, User, Job, and the associated table JobDenial.  JobDenial has a belongs_to relationship with User & Job.

I have an ongoing Job ActiveRecord that is qualifying on a number of different things, but I need to add the additional condition, so that it disregards jobs where the job_id and the current user_id are found on JobDenial.

I can do this currently as:

```
job_ids = current_user.job_denials.map(&:job_id)

jobs = Job.near(params[:zipcode], distance).where('active = true AND id NOT IN (?)', job_ids).select(:id).uniq
```

.... but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this with out resulting to getting a map first of job_ids.

Comment: I would change `map(&:job_id)` to `pluck(:job_id)`, and write `where` as: `where(active: true).where.not(id: job_ids)`. But would definitively use same approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I might add a few scopes to `Job` similar to:

```
scope :active, ->{ where(active: true) }
scope :approved, -> { includes(:job_denials).where(job_denials: {id: nil}) }
```

Change the naming however seems best for your app, but this allows you to use simple, easy-to-read chains to pull your Job data

```
Job.active.approved
current_user.jobs.active.approved.near(...)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be:

```
jobs = Job.includes(:job_denials)
          .where(active: true)
          .where(job_denials: {job_id: nil})
          .near(params[:zipcode], distance)
```

If you just want to select `id` from job:

```
job_ids = Job.includes(:job_denials)
             .where(active: true)
             .where(job_denials: {job_id: nil})
             .near(params[:zipcode], distance)
             .pluck(:id)
```